Multiple domains and multiple certificates pointing to one MVC app
With our in-house system there is small app that reads the domain name at the IIS root from the incoming request - if it's one that is managed by us it is directed to the customer website held on the same IIS Server, if not it goes to our corporate one - the entire site html is held on a back-end DB and formed then so each one appears unique.
This has worked well in the past as the domains were basic http - if they needed to make a payment the domain was switched to one of our own with a ssl cert. These days any site without a cert is being flagged by modern browsers and it's enough of a pain in the rump ordering and updating the certificates for six domains never mind hundreds.
So, the question being - with Azure - can we just register a domain, point it to the app ip address, then somehow configure Azure to accept the new domain and issue a certificate?

Please provide more details about the issue and what you tried .

Hi Harshitha. At the moment I am trying to determine if such a combination is possible. Sales don't know and all they can offer is raising a support ticket, but that is kinda horse before the cart. I understand that this platform is generally to fix code, but I can't find an answer to this one anywhere.

Yes, a single App can have multiple domains and certificates by using Azure App Service.

To know the limit of no. of domains and certificates, refer this App Service limits

As per this MSDoc, single App can have multiple certificates and domains with the same IP.

**SNI SSL allows  - Multiple SNI SSL bindings may be added. This option allows multiple TLS/SSL certificates to secure multiple domains on the same IP address.


In Azure App Service => Custom domains => Add custom domain


you will find an option to select the SSL  Certificate and Type.

Select the App Service Managed Certificate and SNI SSL type.



This has worked well in the past as the domains were basic http

Also refer this blogs 1 and 2 for more details.

Thank you for taking the time to point me in the right direction. A while ago I did deploy a test site with SSL cert. It's going to take some time to read the documentation in the first link, but I did notice in the MSDoc link that I can use a script with PowerShell to automate it, which will be really handy.
